# корректно изменить адрес не нарушая СORS

Tags: javascript, html5, cors

Проблема такая, хочу чтобы по клику изменялось содержимое блока, но моя функция не проходит проверку, вот текст ошибки: Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: Политика одного источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса на file://......./catalog.html. (Причина: запрос CORS выполнен не по http).
Вопрос: как сделать правильно, при этом стили изменяет как нужно?

КОД HTML:

```
<li class="menu_catalog" onclick="click_menu('catalog')"><a href="#content">Каталог лазеров</a></li>
```

КОД JS:

```
function click_menu(){
var url_adress= '12';
var css= '12';
var name= '12';
var sub_name= '12';
if ('catalog'){
    var url_adress='catalog.html';
    var css= 'catalog.css';
    var name= 'Каталог';
};
console.log(25);
$('#content').load('./pages/products/'+url_adress);
$('link:last').attr('href', 'css/'+css);
$('.active').html(name);}
```

Comment: Протокол `file://...`? Поднимите нормальные веб-сервер (nginx, apache, iis, что угодно). Нет никакого смысла что-то делать с CORS если вы используете неправильный протокол.

Comment: Прошу прощения, я то еще профан, если сайт можно посмотреть через GitHub Pages , то должно грузиться как надо?

Comment: @АртемРуденков, при загрузке на GitHub Pages ошибка пропадет